# Set SplitView Controller as root controller after Login IOS

Tags: ios7, ipad, rootview

Hi I am new to IOS development and developing IOS application in which I am using split view controller. My split view controller is not at root position.I am doing login first and then open split view controller. So what I did after user login successful I am changing root view controller. Here is what I did till now:

On sign in button click I am changing root view controller as split view controller like this

```
- (IBAction)signinAction:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"inside sign in .... ");
    AppDelegate *delegate =  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    delegate.window.rootViewController = [[UserProfileController alloc] init];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

User profile is my detail view controller for my split view.

```
@interface UserProfileController : UIViewController<UISplitViewControllerDelegate>

@end
```

but after click sign in button it opens black window. Don't know whats going wrong. Am I doing some thing wrong? Need Help thank you.

Answer (score 0):

first thing you should change id of your `UISplitViewController` to `Split`
after just don't make any connection between your first controller and the split view controller. Then in code switch to it with this code:

```
- (IBAction)signinAction:(id)sender

{   
UISplitViewController *split = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Split"];
self.view.window.rootViewController = split;
}
```